# Trigger Oracle operator LIKE to respect a string format

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to learn how triggers work and how to write them properly with a given exercise. I'm using SQL Developper with the version 4.2 of Oracle.

I have a table PERSON with these fields : 'matricule', 'pmatricule' and 'typpers'.

'typpers' is a letter to show if the person is a student (E), a professor (P) or other (X). 'matricule' is a chain of 3 to 7 numbers and 'matricule' is a chain with 'p' followed by a chain of 3 to 6 numbers. Example : 'p145', 'p123456'.

I want my trigger to check if the format of 'matricule' or 'pmatricule' is respected when someone wants to insert a row in the table PERSON.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_matricule
  BEFORE INSERT ON PERSONNE
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  new_pmatricule PERSONNE.pmatricule%type;  
BEGIN
  IF((:NEW.TYPPERS = 'P' OR :NEW.TYPPERS = 'X') AND :NEW.pmatricule NOT LIKE 'p%______') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'pmatricule format is not good');
  END IF;
END;
```

My trigger works if I'm trying to insert a 'pmatricule' format like '52p' but it also activates when I'm trying to insert such as 'p145'.

I assume that my syntax is not good enough but I'm not finding the proper syntax to do that.

Has anyone an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, simplify the syntax for the first part of the expression using `in`.  Then, if you want to count the number of characters, leave out the `'%'`.  Something like this:

```
  IF((:NEW.TYPPERS IN ('P', 'X') AND :NEW.pmatricule NOT LIKE 'p______') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'pmatricule format is not good');
  END IF;
```

This says that the "p" needs to be followed by six characters.  Your version says "at least 6 characters".

If you want two characters followed by a p, it would be:

```
:NEW.pmatricule NOT LIKE '__p'
```

Any number followed by a "p" would be:

```
:NEW.pmatricule NOT LIKE '%p'
```

If you want more advanced pattern matching, you probably want to use `regexp_like()`.  It is much more versatile.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you want:

```
where regexp_like(:NEW.pmatricule, '^p[0-9]{3,6}$')
```

This is probably the easiest way to write the condition.

If you mean 3-6 *characters*, you can use the cumbersome:

```
where :NEW.pmatricule like 'p___' or
      :NEW.pmatricule like 'p____' or
      :NEW.pmatricule like 'p_____' or
      :NEW.pmatricule like 'p______'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I see my fault but what I'm trying to write is 'p' followed by at least 3 numbers and at max 6 numbers.

Is there no 'easy' syntax (without using regex_like()) for this case ?

Comment: Yeah that's why I was thinking about but it's so ugly. But are you sure that that '_' can only be replaced by numbers ? Because you say 'characters' and characters can be letters or numbers.
(sorry for the double post but I can't edit my first answer)

Comment: @MbrMbr . . . `_` can replace *any* character.  I thought the answer was clear on that point.

Comment: Yeah I understand that point but for example 'p___' can be replaced by 'p456' or 'pabc' since '_' can replace any character right ? What I'm trying to say is that I want ONLY numbers after the 'p'

Comment: @MbrMbr . . . That's why I suggest the regular expression.